# Is it possible to enchant IndustrialCraft items?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-industrialcraft

I have a nano saber, a mining drill, and some Quantum Bodyarmor. Can I enchant them? If so, how? Us, I do want to do this in survival mode.

Also, I hear (mostly on Reddit) that you can enchant tools like this with an uncrafting table. How?

Comment: This is trivial with server op commands or Creative Mode, so can we assume you mean whether it's possible for a normal survival player?

Comment: You could just...try it?

Comment: @Alice You can't in an enchanting table—that's well known. Is there any way at all then, is the question.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Ah, fairy snuff.

Comment: @AliceRees I know right? I'd love to have Protection IV on my jetpack. Love that thing, but it makes me a squishy target for mobs.

Comment: Just tried crafting a new Nano Saber with an existing enchanted sword in an Uncrafting Table, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it seems it was possible in some old version of IC2, but it was considered bug and was fixed. But I can't find changelog where it was done.

Yes, but not directly. You need to use enchanted books.
As for what enchants, I would guess mining drill counts as normal tool, nano saber as weapon and Quantum armor as armor. So enchant accordingly.

Comment: Just tested: does not work in Survival mode. (It does work in Creative mode, but that's to be expected since you can put any enchant on any item while in Creative mode.)

Comment: I recall seeing a changelog somewhere that says this is no longer possible, but I can't find it right off.

Comment: http://forum.feed-the-beast.com/threads/enchanted-jetpack.9684/

Comment: So what is the deal with this with the current build? Is or isn't it possible with survival mode? I perhaps need to start a new question but then the tunnel vision people close it with a link to this thread.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested it in IC2 experimental.  there was no way to enchant the saber using any mechanic.  The enchanting table did nothing when the saber was inserted.  i tried books and an anvil using books from all 3 item classes (tool, weapon, armor).  I even attempted using server /enchant commands.  These all denied enchants on the saber.   I did not attempt the mining laser or the armors.

I know you are probably not using experimental, but this will give you an idea of what to expect from the IC2 Dev team in future builds.

Answer (score 0):

In ftb ultimate reload you can use an anvil with certain enchantes to put them on.

Comment: Okay, but does the OP mention that/those, or have access to them? How is this helpful if not?