# Can drills (and other FTB tools) be enchanted in survival mode?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

First of all i am aware of this question: 
[Is it possible to enchant IndustrialCraft items?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/112444/is-it-possible-to-enchant-industrialcraft-items)

> The answer from Euphoric states it can be done using books. This is
>   confirmed by the FTB-wiki: *This item cannot be enchanted
>   traditionally, however can be enchanted using books.*
>
> However in the comments of that particular answer SevenSidedDie notes
>   that this only works on creative mode where every item can be
>   enchanted. *Just tested: does not work in Survival mode. (It does work
>   in Creative mode, but that's to be expected since you can put any
>   enchant on any item while in Creative mode.)*

I cannot find a clear internet source for this, some say it cannot be done while some say you can. So can drills and other FTB tools be enchanted by books or other means? And if not, are there mods that allow this?

Comment: Hey man, YOu can offer a bounty on the other question to get new information and such but this will likely get closed as a duplicate since all this is asking is for the other answer to be validated/brought up to date.

Comment: Then we will never know since i do not think a bounty will help the question i quoted as it stands now. I tried commenting on the answer but that did not yield information at all. I might cheat on another world to see if i can enchant drills somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes many power tools and special armor can be enchanted. This may not be working as intended, so keep in mind future patches and updates may remove your enchantments. Use an anvil and an enchanted book of your requested effect, and voila!, your new drill or chainsaw now has Fortune I! Keep in mind that if you enchant an item that runs on an internal battery, and you allow that battery to run dry, the enchantment will be lost.

I personally do this to my Advanced Diamond Drill every game.

Comment: Keep in mind that the anvil will incur additional level cost. A drill or chainsaw can be enchanted with the same enchantments that work on pick/shovel and axe respectively. A Power Tool can also be enchanted.

Answer (score -1):

They are not meant to be enchanted and in survival it is definitely not possible. I am not aware of any mod that would allow you to enchant them, however you could ask someone who developes mods to make such a mod. However, a lot of vanilla enchants wouldn't make sense on an electric tool anyway.

Comment: Well i just created a new survival world and cheated myself some items and experience. I was able to enchant my drill with "efficiency I". This is clearly an unknown topic. I will answer my question and post screenshots when i did a bit more research.